# The set of $x \in C[a,b]$ such that $|x(t) - x_0| \le c \beta$ is closed in $C[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

$
\newcommand{\set}[1]{ \left\{ #1 \right\} }
\newcommand{\setb}[2]{ \left\{ #1 \; \middle| \; #2 \right\} }
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\ve}{\varepsilon}
$
**Simplified Version of the Problem:** Recall that we may define the following:

$$C[a,b] := \setb{ f : [a,b] \to \R }{ f \text{ is continuous on } [a,b] }$$

With the metric $d$ endowed by the supremum norm, this is a complete metric space. The metric, for clarity, is

$$d(f,g) := \max_{t \in [a,b]} \Big| f(t) - g(t) \Big|$$

Define a subset $B$ of $C[a,b]$ as follows:

$$B := \setb{ f \in C[a,b] }{ |f(t)-1| \le 2 }$$

I wish to prove that $B$ is closed.

---

**More General Context/Application/Background:** This comes up in the proof of [Picard's existence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), presented in Kreyszig's *Introduction to Functional Analysis with Applications,* and is left as a problem to the reader in section $\S 5.3$, problem $6$. It is, however, much more general that the version I stated above. In particular (up to notational differences), we instead have the following:

- Let $f(t,x)$ be continuous on the rectangle in $\R^2$ given by $R := [t_0 - a, t_0 + a] \times [x_0 - b, x_0 + b]$.
- $f$ also has a Lipschitz condition on its second component: $|f(t,x) - f(t,v)| \le k|x-v|$ $\forall (t,x),(t,v) \in R$
- $f$, moreover, is bounded: $|f(t,x)| \le c$ for a certain constant $c$.
- Of particular concern is the initial value problem $x' = f(t,x)$ with $x(t_0) = x_0$. (Picard's theorem is concerned in this context of showing the solution to this exists, is unique, and lies on $J$ as below.)
- Define $J := [t_0 - \beta, t_0 + \beta]$, for a constant $\beta$ such that $\beta < \min \{a, b/c, 1/k\}$
- Define $B$ to be the set of $x \in C(J)$ such that $|x(t) - x_0| \le c \beta$.

In the proof of the theorem, one is meant to see that $B$ is a closed subset of $C(J)$. The completeness of $C(J)$ then gives completion to all of its closed subsets, namely $B$, which we later use to apply the Banach contraction principle: we define an operator $T : B \to B$, which happens to be a contraction, and then the principle gives us a unique fixed point, which is critical for the proof.

Of course, many of these details are not strictly related to showing that $B$ (in this more general context, even) is closed. This is in part why I developed the much simpler formulation at the start, to avoid overcomplicating matters with symbols and notation that don't make sense. So if you prefer working with the simpler version initially presented, or want the more general one I am working with, either works for me -- insights into one no doubt would play into the other.

---

**Attempts So Far:** For what is a comparatively complicated proof, proving $B$ is closed has evaded me for a bit; I guess because I'm not too used to working with metrics tied to functions? (Below, I'm working in the more general context the proof demands.)

So far my idea is this. Take $\set{f_n}_{n \in \N} \subseteq B \subseteq C[a,b]$ a sequence in $B$ converging to $f$; this would ensure that $f \in B'$ (definition of limit point), and we want to show that $f \in B$ in particular (a set is closed iff it contains its limit points). Note that since $C[a,b]$ is complete, then $f \in C[a,b]$ for sure (as $\set{f_n}$ is assumed convergent, thus is Cauchy in $C[a,b]$, and $C[a,b]$ is complete, so the limit is in $C[a,b]$).

Since $f_n \in B$ $\forall n \in \N$, then, $\forall t \in J$, it holds that

$$|f_n(t) - x_0 | \le c \beta$$

Consider the quantity $|f(t) - x_0|$. From the convergence $f_n \to f$ and continuity of metrics, it holds that

$$|f(t) - x_0| = \left| \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(t) - x_0 \right| = \lim_{n \to \infty} |f_n(t) - x_0| \le c \beta$$

(where the inequality holds in the limit since, otherwise, there would be some point $M$ where $|f_n(t) - x_0| > c \beta$ $\forall n \ge M$, contradicting that $f_n \in B$ $\forall n \in \N$). From this, thus, $f$ has the defining property of being in $B$; thus, $f \in B$.

---

**My Questions:**

My questions are mostly straighforward: does this approach work? Are there any logical or rigorous failings? I just feel somewhat unconfident in it, so I'd like to have some second opinions (or better/correct explanations).

Thanks for any insights you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is correct. In general if you have a set given by a "continuous" equality or (not strict ) inequality for example $B=\{ x \in X | F(x)≤C\} $ you can use a similar argument by assuming that you have a convergent sequence $(a_n)_n \rightarrow a $ and you can show that $F(a_n)≤C \implies F(a)≤C$ because $F$ is continuous and you can interchange $F$ and the limit.